# How to remove the order clause of a subquery issued by Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When using Sequelize, I want to specify the order clause only for the main query, but the order clause is also applied to subqueries.
How can I apply the order clause to the main query only?

### environment

■ Sequelize version

3.30.4

■ RDB

MySQL 5.7

### DB design

- Parents

  - id
- Children

  - id
  - parent_id

### Relationships defined in Sequelize

```js
Parents.hasMany(models.Children, {
    foreignKey: 'parent_id'
});
Children.belongsTo(models.Parents, {
    foreignKey: 'parent_id'
});
```

### ORM

```js
Parents.findOne({
    order: "id asc",
    include: [Children]
})
```

### SQL

```sql
SELECT
    `Parents`.*,
    `Children`.`id` AS `Children.id`,
    `Children`.`parent_id` AS `Children.parent_id`,
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            `Parents`.`id`,
        FROM
            `Parents` AS `Parents`
        ORDER BY
            id asc
        LIMIT
            1
    ) AS `Parents`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `Children` AS `Children` ON `Parents`.`id` = `Children`.`parent_id`
ORDER BY
    id asc;
```

subquery

```
ORDER BY id asc
```

I would like to delete the order